# Which Document need to be created first by a Business Analyst? Scope Document or Business Requirement Document(BRD)?

Tags: business-analyst

Do the following documents need to be created by a Business Analyst in any particular order? If so, what?

1. Scope Document
2. Business Requirement Document (BRD)
3. Functional Specification Document (FRD/FRS)

Comment: As written, this is likely to be closed as either unclear or too broad. Please provide more context, and explain why your current approach isn’t working for you.

Comment: I don't know that this is too broad or unclear.  There's a logical order in these products, where it is not possible to write one without the other.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have them listed is standard: Scope, then BRD, then FRD.

I typically recommend consolidating all of them into a single document, unless there is some overriding reason to keep them separate.